# Apply matrix dot between a list of matrices and a list of vectors in Numpy

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array, linear-algebra, numpy-ndarray

Let's suppose I have these two variables

```py
matrices = np.random.rand(4,3,3)
vectors = np.random.rand(4,3,1)
```

What I would like to perform is the following:

```py
dot_products = [matrix @ vector for (matrix,vector) in zip(matrices,vectors)]
```

Therefore, I've tried using the `np.tensordot` method, which at first seemed to make sense, but this happened when testing

```
>>> np.tensordot(matrices,vectors,axes=([-2,-1],[-2,-1]))
...
ValueError: shape-mismatch for sum 
>>> np.tensordot(matrices,vectors,axes=([-2,-1]))
...
ValueError: shape-mismatch for sum
```

Is it possible to achieve these multiple dot products with the mentioned Numpy method? If not, is there another way that I can accomplish this using Numpy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation for `@` is found at `np.matmul`.  It is specifically designed for this kind of 'batch' processing:

```
In [76]: matrices = np.random.rand(4,3,3)
    ...: vectors = np.random.rand(4,3,1)

In [77]: dot_products = [matrix @ vector for (matrix,vector) in zip(matrices,vectors)]
In [79]: np.array(dot_products).shape
Out[79]: (4, 3, 1)

In [80]: (matrices @ vectors).shape
Out[80]: (4, 3, 1)

In [81]: np.allclose(np.array(dot_products), matrices@vectors)
Out[81]: True
```

A couple of problems with `tensordot`.  The `axes` parameter specify which dimensions are summed, "dotted",  In your case it would be the last of `matrices` and 2nd to the last of `vectors`.  That's the standard `dot` paring.

```
In [82]: np.dot(matrices, vectors).shape
Out[82]: (4, 3, 4, 1)
In [84]: np.tensordot(matrices, vectors, (-1,-2)).shape
Out[84]: (4, 3, 4, 1)
```

You tried to specify 2 pairs of axes for summing.  Also `dot/tensordot` does a kind of `outer product` on the other dimensions.  You'd have to take the "diagonal" on the 4's.  `tensordot` is not what you want for this operation.

We can be more explicit about the dimensions with `einsum`:

```
In [83]: np.einsum('ijk,ikl->ijl',matrices, vectors).shape
Out[83]: (4, 3, 1)
```

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know that `np.matmul` could handle this operation, also `np.einsum` is very interesting, I'll give a look into it.